# How to structure command line app so it can make an HTTP request?

Tags: swift, macos, command-line, urlsession

I'm trying to learn Swift by writing a command line app.  When I run the app, unless I use dispatchMain(), I never see the HTTP response.  At the same time, once the HTTP reqeust has completed, the app never ends.  Is there a common practice for how to build swift apps for command line use vs iOS/macOS?

```
import Foundation

let apiToken = "EkLNXi5sD2ZtH2YMuSEt8J3Yo35Od4n" // This is where you store your token as a variable
let urlString = "https://echo.free.beeceptor.com/"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

let json: [String: Any] = ["key": "value", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"]

func send_telemetry(apitoken: String, url: URL, json: [String: Any]) {

    print("  apitoken: \(apitoken)")
    print("  URL:      \(url)")
    print("  JSON:     \(json)")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(apitoken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")  // Using the variable here

    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []) {
        request.httpBody = jsonData
    } else {
        print("Error: couldn't create JSON data.")
        return
    }

    // Sending the Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in     
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Error occurred: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            return
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Received HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode) - \(HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode: httpResponse.statusCode))")
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            print("HTTP Error:", httpResponse.statusCode)
        }

        do {
            if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                print(jsonResponse)
            }
        } catch {
            print("JSON parsing error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    print("Starting the request...")
    task.resume()
    print("Task scheduled")
}

func main() {
    print("Program Starting...")
    send_telemetry(apitoken: apiToken, url: url, json: json)
    print("Program Ending...")
}

main()
dispatchMain()
```

Comment: You need to avoid your program to end the end of the "file", else it will terminate there. You have an asynchronous method, so without your add-on, it's reach the end, and ends the app without having the response from your URLSession. To avoid that, you can use async/await, or use a trick to keep the app from reaching the end with something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590701/multiple-workers-in-swift-command-line-tool